# HTML webpage does not display properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Playing around with html and css, with the help of twitter bootstrap, but 1) I can't seem to fix the extra space on the right side and 2) I cant add anymore content on the bottom of my webpage.

You can view the live site here: practicerenz.kissr.com

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Practice Renz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <h1 class="title">Renz Site</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                                <li><img class="social1" src="img/facebook.png" /></li>
                                <li><img class="social2" src="img/twitter_light.png" /></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="maintitle">
                <img src="img/user.png" />
                <h1 class="name">I am Renzze Mistal.</h1>
                <p class="occupation">Digital Marketer | Rookie Developer</p> <br />
                <p class="info">I like to create and design things. I like to create and design things. I like to create and design things.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="work">
                <img class="workimg" src="img/Dashboard.png" />
                <h1 class="info2"><a name="work">My Work</a></h1>
                <p class="info2">Here are some of the things that I've done.</p>
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/work.png">
                        <p class="info3">Brand 1</p>
                        <p class="info3">Info info info info info</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/work.png">
                        <p class="info3">Brand 2</p>
                        <p class="info3">Info info info info info</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="img/work.png">
                        <p class="info3">Brand 3</p>
                        <p class="info3">Info info info info info</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="button">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Learn more</button>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="blog">
                <img src="img/Comment.png">
                <h1 class="blogname"><a class="blogtitle" name="blog">Blog</a></h1>
                <p class="bloginfo">Read some of the stuff I've written.</p>
                <img src="img/blog.png">
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <p>Leave me a message below</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.col-xs-8 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
body {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    margin: 0 auto
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
ul {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.title {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.container {
        width: 1024px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #2c3e50;
}
.maintitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 300px;
}
.info {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.occupation {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.work {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    height: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
.info2 {
        color: #2c3e50;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
}
.name {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.social1 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.social2 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline;
}
.mywork {
    display: inline;

}
.info3 {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.blog {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.blogname {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.bloginfo {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.blogtitle {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.workimg {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Appreciate any help! :)

P.S. Sorry if my HTML and CSS look messy.

Comment: where spaces in site,where you want to add content or which section

Comment: I don't see any abnormal space on the right side. Your blog is overlapping your contact section. You can probably remove the height from the blog and let it compute the height automatically. As it stands right now, the blog contents are larger than the containing div element.

Comment: Provide a JsFiddle for such things, it makes life easier ;)

Comment: @DavidHoude The header does not extend all the way to the right. Noted on the removal of the height. Thanks!

Comment: @pduersteler Will check JsFiddle now. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I am a little confused. The header does not extend all the way left either. Did you want it centered as it is now, or to have a margin on the left while extending all the way right?

Comment: @DavidHoude I wanted it to cover all. Meaning, white from left to right. As of now, there's a space which shows the blue bg color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove height in blog class.the contact will be clear

```
.blog {
    background-color: #2980B9;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`body{height:100%}` is wrong, you need to change that.

Comment: By change, do you mean remove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your 'header' outside of your 'container' as its width of 1024 is limiting the header width.

```
<div class="header">
 <div class="row">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
</div>


.row { width: 1024px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.header { width: 100%; }
```